# Formula to find out how many times accounts transacted on the same day

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a way to find out which accounts appear to transact on the same days together the most.

I have looked into using the correlation function, but decided this would not provide the results I am looking for as I would need to be able to do this among the 6000+ different acct #s. Therefore, I have decided to try to solve this by creating a matrix of the account #s and finding out how many times each account transacted on the same day as another account, but I am open to other ideas of solving this if anyone has a better idea.

My source data is a large dataset consisting of 2 columns - Date (Column A) and Acct # (Column B).

I am currently looking into sum product, but since I do not want to look at any specific date, rather the date range as a whole, I am not getting what I want.

```
=sumproduct(('Trxs'!A:A='Trxs'!A:A)*('Trxs'!B:B=A$2)*('Trxs'!B:B=$a2))
```

What I am looking for would be a formula that I could use to pull across a matrix of the acct #s that would add up the number of times each of the 2 acct #s transacted on the same date over the time span of a month and not using a specific date to figure this out by.

```
1/1/2019    123456
1/1/2019    987654
1/2/2019    987654
1/3/2019    123456
1/3/2019    123456
1/3/2019    987654
1/3/2019    567890
```

and the outcome would be

```
       123456   567890    987654
123456   3         1        2
567890   1         1        1
987654   2         1        3
```

Comment: Is the outcome you posted based on the actual data you posted?

Comment: @Domenic yes that is correct

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand how you've come up with those results.  Can you edit your post and run through about 3 examples of how the calculation  takes place?

Comment: @Domenic it's a matrix of the # of times the accounts transacted on the same days together. For example column 1 row 1 is just a count of how many times acct 123456 transacted . Column 1 row 2 is a count of how many times account 123456 transacted on the same day as 567890. Column 1 row 3 is the count of how many times account 123456 transacted on the same day as 987654.

Comment: @Domenic sorry there was a typo in the example matrix. Maybe that was what was throwing you off?

Comment: someone asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57500746/excel-count-instances-that-have-matching-combinations/57504486#57504486) which was also answered by Kaiser with the same approach. I cam up with an approach without using helper table which might be what you are looking for. Have a look and let me know if my approach is applicable to your case. Cheers :)

Comment: Yes that looks like what I was looking for. Thank you this is a very valuable solution.greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've came up with a solution using a helper table that counts if that account had activity that day:

[image]

The formula for the cell F12 on the helper table is:

```
=+IF(COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$12,$E12,$C$3:$C$12,F$11)>0,1,0)
```

And the formula on the Final Resul table:

Edit 2: I agree with Domenic, the formula on cell F4 works better with the IF section:

```
=IF($E4<>F$3,SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($F$12:$J$14,0,MATCH($E4,$F$11:$J$11)),INDEX($F$12:$J$14,0,MATCH(F$3,$F$11:$J$11))),COUNTIF($C$3:$C$12,$E4))
```

Comment: This looks like it could work but I was hoping to do it without a helper table. There is also an additional element I was hoping to account for later where the accounts are associated to the dates and a location and was hoping that I could bring that in as well with slight modification to whatever formula was created to solve this part. But given the helper table method not sure how I would bring that element in for consideration.

Comment: Meaning that if acct 12345 transacted on 01/01/2019 at location abc and acct 98765 transacted on 01/01/2019 at location abc then it would count as 1 but if the locations were different it would not count

Comment: @Kaiser's solution should be more efficient.  However, I think the second formula should be `=IF($E4<>F$3,SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($F$12:$J$14,0,MATCH($E4,$F$11:$J$11,0)),INDEX($F$12:$J$14,0,MATCH(F$3,$F$11:$J$11,0))),COUNTIF($C$3:$C$12,$E4))`.

Comment: By the way, regarding @Kaiser's first formula, the `+` sign isn't needed.  So you could simply have `=IF(....)`.

Comment: The + signs is because I use to start the formulas with it because is faster to type than the = and when the formula is saved it creates de =+, but it’s not needed for sure ;)

Comment: @Kaiser First, my sincere apologies.  Your original solution was fine, as long as the OP ensures that the account numbers listed in the helper table are sorted in ascending order, and each account number listed in the results table occurs in the helper table, as per your example.  Setting the MATCH functions for an approximate match instead of an exact match, as you did, is more efficient.  I think your formula only needed to be amended to include the IF part.

Comment: Hi Domenic, no worries, I’ve updated as per your comments, cheers

Comment: I gave you a `+1` for a very nice solution.  Cheers!