# EXCEL- Count instances that have matching combinations

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, countif

I’m pretty good at excel but for some reason can’t find the right solution to this problem (maybe I’m over complicating it):

Basically I have 2 columns with info like below:

```
Column 1    Column 2
A                  Red
A                  Blue
A                  Yellow
B                  Blue
B                  Green
B                  Brown
C                  Red
C                  Blue
C                  Brown
```

What I want is to create a cross tab type of table which counts how many items in column 1 have the correct combination of values in column 2

For instance, I’d expect the result below:

```
         Red      Blue     Brown
Red   2            2            1
```

Red-Red would evaluate to 2 because there are 2 instances in column 1 where the items have Red in Column 2

Red-Blue would evaluate to 2 because there are two instances where the values in column A have values of both Red and Blue in column 2 (A-Red/A-Blue and C-Red/C-Blue)

Red-Brown would evaluate to 1 because C is only value in Column 1 that has a value of Red and Brown in Column 2

I hope that’s clear. I’ve tried multiple combinations of countifs/sumifs but haven’t had any luck getting the desired result. :(

Comment: you can use an array formula, in combination with count, and then a double condition. (finish entering array formula with ctrl shift enter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formula to find out how many times accounts transacted on the same day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907211/formula-to-find-out-how-many-times-accounts-transacted-on-the-same-day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Formula based approach**

[image: Solution]

The formula in Cell **E2** in my solution is as below, and as it is an **array formula** you need to press **`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`** to make it work.

```
{=SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(IF((Column_1&$D2=Column_1&Column_2),Column_1)&E$1,Column_1&Column_2,0)))}
```

Please note I have added some sample data to your original set, and I've **named** the following ranges:

**Column_1** stands for all data in the first column A;

**Column_2** stands for all data in the second column B.

My logic is to

1. Use **IF** function and **`=`** to find out, for a given color in **Column D**, what is the corresponding value in **Column_1**? If we are looking at **Red** in cell `D2`, my IF function will return the following 
   `{"A";FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;"C";FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;"D";FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}`;
2. Use **`&`** to combine the range from last step with the look up value in Row 1. If we combine the range with **Red** in cell `E1`, we will have 
   `{"ARed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed";"CRed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed";"DRed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed";"FALSERed"}`;
3. Next step is to **MATCH** the range from last step with the given combination which is `Column_1&Column_2` that represents **ARed**, **ABlue**, **AYellow**, **BBlue**, **BGreen**, etc. Continue with my example the results would be
   `{1;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;7;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;11;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A}` in which the **numerical values** are the positions of **ARed**, **CRed**, and **DRed** in the range of the given combination `Column_1&Column_2`.
4. The last step to use **ISNUMBER** to find out how many values within the range from last step are number, which shall return 
   `{TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}`
   and then **SUM** up all **TRUE** results by converting them into numerical value `1` using **`--`**.

> **Power Query Based Approach**

Using the same source data in my solution, `A1:B16`, load this to the **Power Query Editor**, then you should have the following:

[image: Sorted]

Please note I have **sorted** the table by Column 2 and then Column 1 ascending consecutively. This is an optional step just to help making the following steps easier to be understood.

The next step is to **merge** the table with its own by matching **Column 1**:

[image: merge]

**Expand** the new column to show Column 2:

[image: expand]

**Highlight the last column**, use **Pivot Column** function to transform the table, then you should have:

[image: Pivot Column]

The only problem is that the colors will be positioned differently to the source.

If it is important to keep the colors in original order, one way of doing that is to

1. create a **look up table** showing the desired order of the colors with an **index column**;
2. **merge** this look up table **before pivot column** in the first query, and match the colors in the **third column**, expand and sort the index column and then remove it;
3. do the Pivot Column, and then **merger the look up table again**, and expand, sort and remove the index column again.

Here are the codes behind the scene for reference only:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column 1", type text}, {"Column 2", type text}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Column 2", Order.Ascending}, {"Column 1", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Sorted Rows", {"Column 1"}, #"Sorted Rows", {"Column 1"}, "Filtered Rows", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Filtered Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Filtered Rows", {"Column 2"}, {"Filtered Rows.Column 2"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Filtered Rows"[#"Filtered Rows.Column 2"]), "Filtered Rows.Column 2", "Column 1", List.Count)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: This method worked perfectly!!! The only down side is because I have a large dataset it takes a long time to calculate.

Comment: @Capple the downside of using array formulas is that it may slow down your calculation for large data set. Make sure you only name the relevant range in Column A and B instead of name the full column A:A and B:B as the range. Not sure if you are open to a solution by Power Query? With a few clicks in the power query editor you will get the desired result quite easily. Let me know if you are interested and I can add it to my current solution. Power Query is faster in some scenarios when running large volume of data but it needs to be tested case wise. Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, I’m definitely open to a power query solution. I use it often and tried a few different methods there as well, but nothing that achieved the desired result. As of right now my comparison table is ~19K rows so you can imagine the time it takes to calculate via the array method.

Comment: @Capple I have added the power query solution hope it makes sense. Please do let me know if using power query in your case is significantly faster than using array formulas. Thanks.

Comment: I’m my previous attempts the only thing I didn’t try was merging against the same table, but that was the missing step and PERFECT solution. The PQ method works at lightening speed in comparison to using the array method (from 2 hours to 2-3 mins). Thanks a million! I hope anyone with the same issue would find this thread and save themselves hours.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version using Sum and Countifs (maybe the sort of thing that @AlexT82 was thinking of):

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10,IF($B$2:$B$10=$D2,E$1)))
```

Must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Assumes that each colour only occurs once for each item in Column 1.

You should be able to correct for any repeats within an item by dividing by the number of times they occur within each item:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,$A$2:$A$12,$B$2:$B$12,IF($B$2:$B$12=$D2,E$1))
/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,$A$2:$A$12,$B$2:$B$12,$D2)/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,$A$2:$A$12,$B$2:$B$12,E$1),0))
```

[image]

Comment: never know **COUNTIFS** can be used in such an interesting way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution below that uses a helper table that counts what you're looking for:

[image]

The formula for the cell F12 on the helper table is:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$12,$E12,$C$3:$C$12,F$11)>0,1,0)
```

And the formula on the Final Result table:

```
 =IF($E4<>F$3,SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($F$12:$J$14,0,MATCH($E4,$F$11:$J$11)),INDEX($F$12:$J$14,0,MATCH(F$3,$F$11:$J$11))),COUNTIF($C$3:$C$12,$E4))
```

Note: This is a recycled answer from a similar question, see the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56908737/3813846).